# How to use ng-show on a form button with custom repeating validators

Tags: angularjs, forms, ng-show

I have a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ntsim/41jfu7t9/

I have an ng application that uses an ng-repeat to display an array of monetary values. These values must be of the form n.nn (a positive floating pt number with two decimal places) or n (a positive integer).

Each repeating input box has a pattern test which sets an error flag (myform.texter.$error.pattern), so if this pattern is present I can show an error message next to the input box that has the error. That all works

At the end of the form I have an “Add” button that I will use to add these numbers. The add button Is always shown now, but i only want this button to appear if all the text boxes contain valid patterns, something like:

`<button ng-show=“myform….”>Add<button>`

But I cant get this to show/hide to work on the add button. How can I do this in angular with the show/hide?

The code for my template is shown below:

```
<div ng-repeat="price in prices">
  <form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="texter" ng-model="price" ng-pattern="monetaryRegex" \>

    <span ng-show="myForm.texter.$error.pattern">
      Invalid (use 5 or 5.00 for example)!</span>
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<button ng-hide="myform.texter.$error.pattern">
  <!-- would like to use ng-hide=xxx so that this button does not appear if any numbers are invalid-->
  Add
</button>

My Controller is:

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.instructions = 'Change these price amounts (each must be a  fixed 2 decimal number or an integer) then click Add';

  $scope.prices = [0.32, 12, 45.34, 45];
  $scope.monetaryRegex = /^(([1-9]\d*)?\d)(\.\d\d)?$/;


});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to take advantage of form's nesting. So basically you can do this:

```
<form name="outerForm">
    <div ng-repeat="...">
         <ng-form name="innerForm"></form>
    </div>
</form>
<button ng-hide="outerForm.$error.pattern">Add</button>
```

Here's a [working copy](https://jsfiddle.net/190dL7u9/2/) of your example. That being said, please check the pattern regex. I'm not by any means expert in regexes, but as yours was not working for me, I swapped it for a simple greedy `^[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]$`.

**Edit:** In order your validation messages to work, for the inner form use `ng-form` instead of `form`. Example updated, cheers.

Comment: Thanks very much, that works. I updated my fiddle. BTW your regex pattern didn't quite work for me. My pattern will allow integers (numbers without a decimal), and it seems that your pattern requires all numbers to have the decimal pt. Still you answered the original question, so thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Yeah, as I said, I'm a regex newbie, but the regex is something you can easily tweak to your preferences/requirements : )